# CSS increase +100% image opacity, posible?

Tags: css, image, alpha

I tried **with text** just with: `opacity:3;filter:alpha(opacity=300);` and it works, **but not** with **images**,

any alternative?

Comment: I don't understand. How can anything be more than 100% opaque?

Comment: I can't see through walls even more than I used to not be able to.

Comment: guys try to apply 2 & 200 to text, it gets brighter than original!

Answer (score 7):

If you are trying to make the images darker you cannot do that with opacity higher than 100%. 100% opacity is the most visible, the opacity scale (like in photo/video editing) is from 0 (completely transparent) to 100 (full opacity).

You can however give your image a filter property which will overlay on top of the image. That filter property can do a lot but in this case you would benefit most from the brightness setting of the filter property. 100% brightness will show your image in it's original form, whereas the lower the percent of the brightness the darker the filter will get and thus the darker your image.

It would look something like this:

```
.slide-img{
  width: 100%;
  height: 20%;
  filter: brightness(50%);
}
```

Comment: this worked for me, thanks. In dev tools of chrome, when you set styles for your element you can try filter options shown by chrome. Brightness, contrast, saturate wiith values

Answer (score 2):

Even it it's possible to set opacity values above 100%, there is no benefit to doing so.  Once something is 100% opaque it cannot visibly become any more opaque than that.

What is it that you are trying to accomplish by setting the opacity above 100%?  There may be some other property that will give you the desired effect.

Comment: hello my friend, i would like to mark it as answered but we are missing the 'some other property' that you where about to suggest :$

Comment: It sounds like what you're looking for is a way to brighten/tint an image element, but I don't think there's any standard way of doing so through CSS.  Internet Explorer supports a [filter](http://www.computing.net/answers/webdevel/css-tinting-an-image/848.html) property that can do what you want, but that won't work for other browsers.  Also, you might want to look at [http://csstint.sourceforge.net/](http://csstint.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: If you have an image with semi-transparent pixels, an opacity > 100% could really make sense. E.g. if a pixel in the image has an alpha value of 20%, and you apply 300% opacity to the image, the pixel would be drawn with an alpha value of 60% (like drawing the same image 3x at the same position). I had also hoped that CSS supports this functionality.

Answer (score 0):

[Image Transparency](http://www.w3schools.com/Css/css_image_transparency.asp)

I don't think opacity=300 makes any sense; try opacity=30?

Likewise where you are saying opacity=3, you should try opacity=0.3